# Problem Memory Leak in Core Data code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I can't seem to figure out the cause of a problem reported by the Leaks tool. The code in question is here with the problem line marked. Any ideas? Is there a way to find out exactly what object is the leak?

```
NSArray *getAllCoreData(NSString *entityName, NSString *orderedBy, BOOL ascending, BOOL shallow)
{
// Get the managed object context
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppController sharedAppController] managedObjectContext];

// Create a fetch request that fetches from 'entityName'
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetch setEntity:entity];

// Try to do the fetch
NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]; <----- Problem line

[fetch release];

// Did the fetch fail?
if (!result)
{
    // Display an alert view
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fetch Failed"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription] 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView autorelease];
    [alertView show];
    return nil;
}

// Return the array of instances of NSManagedObject
return result;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Jason

Comment: Hello jason, I am also facing a similar problem so can you please post the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaks is telling you the memory allocated there was kept around after you had no more references.

So after you return results, something else is retaining it too long, and not releasing when you are done.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Apparently tunnel vision had set in and I couldn't see past this routine. My sanity thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
NSError *error;
```

to

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

It may not be a real leak.  Possibly, `NSError *error` just happens to have some leftover pointer in it so it looks like a leak to the tool.

Comment: That wasn't the problem but I've cleaned that up too. Thanks.